# boost::pool::ordered_free() doesn't work well

Tags: c++, boost, memory-management

I'd like to use memory manager and I tried to use `boost::pool` like below, but `ordered_free()` doesn't free all elements.

Sample ↓

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost\pool\pool.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::pool<> p(sizeof(int));
    int* ptr_1= (int*)p.ordered_malloc(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ptr_1[i] = i;
    }
    p.ordered_free(ptr_1);

    int* ptr_2 = (int*)p.ordered_malloc(3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ptr_2[i] = i;
    }

    p.ordered_free(ptr_2);
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, `p.ordered_free(ptr);` deletes only 5 bytes and `ptr_2`'s memory place is not same to `ptr_1`. Is there any way to delete all elements by using `boost::pool`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/interfaces.html#boost_pool.pool.interfaces.ordered_versus_unordered) it looks like `ordered_free(ptr_1)` just deletes one chunk of memory but you can use `ordered_free(ptr_1, 3)` to delete the whole array.